# Android Duplicate files license.txt, handle without license violation

Tags: android

When I try to build my Android application I encounter DuplicateFileExceptions for license files and notice files in APK META-INF for my open source libraries.

I realize that there are many questions here asking about this but each one seems to be answered with excluding or picking the first of each file as a packaging option. Some of the answers contains disclaimers that this might violate open source licenses of libraries used by the application.

How could I solve this problem without violating any license which I assume would be the case if I were to just exclude the files?

Comment: Unpack license from jar, rename it to be some unique(fx license-libx.txt) and put it in resources/META-INF of your project

Comment: @Selvin - Can I make a copy of all the license files from the libraries and put them in a resources with unique names and then exclude as usually suggested? Or do I have to remove them from the jar files?

Comment: Yes because you are excluding the "common names" like license, license.txt, etc. If you add unique name then is should stay in your apk...

Comment: It would be easier if Google would add option to packagingOptions that instead excluding it will be moved to META-INF/libx